# Is there a way to have an alias of a template and preserve Class Template Argument Deduction?

Tags: c++, c++17, ctad

```
#include <vector>

template<class T>
using vec = std::vector<T>;

int main()
{
    std::vector a{2,3};
    // vec b{2,3}; // not going to work
}
```

Are we still forced to use macros? There are so many disadvantages in using them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known problem with CTAD that [has been fixed in C++20](http://wg21.link/p1021)

> Are we still forced to use macros?

No. I'd recommend using `std::vector` if you want CTAD

Comment: So, can you interpret that dense standardese-delta to describe *how* it fixed it?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I replaced it with the non-wording proposal